# How to fix this ValueError: "cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit" if this comes on doing back-fill?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have some data stored in a DataFrame. I dropped and edited some rows but now I am unable to backfill and get the data on an hourly basis.

Now when I am doing this:

```
df5 = df5.set_index("TIMESTAMP").resample("H").bfill().reset_index()
```

I am getting the error mentioned above. How to fill up the data on an hourly basis by back-fill?